# Design pattern for an authentication system in PHP

Tags: php, authentication

I'm learning PHP, and I'm curious if there are elegant solutions to designing an authentication interface for a website.

Basically, I will have three types of users: Regular Users, Admins, and "Power users".
each type of user will have its own actions.

Here is a brief sketch of my current code:

```
# Regular User = Non-Authenticated
interface IRegularUser {
        # Will return an object of a class that implements this interface
        public static function loginUser ($name, $pass);
}

# Authenticated User
class AuthUser extends RegularUser {
        public function logoutUser();
}

interface IAdmin {..}
interface IPowerUser {...}
class User implements IRegularUser {}
class Admin     extends AuthUser implements IAdmin {}
class PowerUser extends AuthUser implements IPowerUser {}
```

In the script that checks for correct login, I would write something similar to this:

```
$user = new User();
$user = $user->loginUser($_POST['username'], $_POST['password']);

if (get_class($user) == get_class(new Admin()))
    # Redirect to admin_home.html   
else if (get_class($user) == get_class(new PowerUser()))
    # Redirect to power_user_home.html
```

I am trying to use the OOP features of PHP, in order to establish some constraints between the entities in my application (Ex: Only by acquiring an User object, you can then login, and acquire an object of type Admin, or PowerUser).

I feel that my authentication system is kind of clunky, and I would like to know if there is a common design pattern for a webapp authentication system.

Comment: "I would like to know if there is a common design pattern for a webapp authentication system." Nope. You seem to have a good start, why not run with that?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Actually, its not that easy as it seems at first glance. There are 3 different aspects when dealing with users, that have roles. The "system" you're looking for would consists of these components:

### Query adapter

Its responsible for finding records match against some adapter. This can query against almost any type, be it `MySQL` table, `XML` file or `Mongo` DB collection. All your query adapters would implement this interface:

```
interface QueryAdapter
{
    public function recordValid($username, $password);
}
```

### Access Control List (ACL/RBAC)

It must be separated layer, that deals with roles and their permissions. Typically

```
$roleManager = new RoleManager();
$roleManager->register(array(
   'admin'     => 'write, edit, read, delete',
   'user'      => 'view',
   'moderator' => 'write, edit, read'
));


$currentUser = get_that_from_session();

if ($roleManager->isAllowed($currentUser, 'write')) {
  // Allow writing
} else {
  echo 'You are not allowed to write';
}
```

## Storage adapter

That is responsible for storing passwords and tokens inside either `$_SESSION` or `$_COOKIE`. If user clicked on *Remember me*, then you would store that info inside `$_COOKIE`, otherwise in `$_SESSION`.

## Typical workflow

To "connect" them all together, you would write it like this : (Keep in mind, this is **extremely simplified** version of it)

```
<?php

$queryAdapter = new Query_Adapter_MySQL($pdo); // or $mongo, whatever

if ($queryAdapter->rowExists($_POST['username'], $_POST['password'])) {

   $role = $queryAdapter->getRole(); // Let's assume that its "user"

   $roleManager = new RoleManager();
   $roleManager->register(array(
      $role => 'read'
   ));

   if (isset($_POST['rememberMe'])){
      $storageAdapter = new StorageAdapter_Cookie();
   } else {
      $storageAdapter = new StorageAdapten_Session();
   }

   $storageAdapter->write(array(
      'role' => $role,
      'passwordHash' => $passwordHash,
      'token' => $token
   ));
}
```

To check if that user logged in, and has a right to do something, you would simply query an adapter to sees that, like,

```
<?php

if ($storageAdapter->isLoggedIn()){

   if ($roleManager->hasRight($storageAdapter->get('role'), 'read')){
      // Allowed to read content
   }
}
```

### What would you gain with this approach?

- Clear separation of responsibilities (This adheres to Single-Responsibility Principle)
- Improved code readability
- Adhering to Dependency Injection (thus making unit-testing possible)
- You can easily switch from MySQL to another storage, without affecting the rest of your code. You would simply inject an instance of the adapter you're going to use.

## Is that it?

Yes. You can also take a look at how Zend Framework [implements this](http://zf2.readthedocs.org/en/latest/modules/zend.authentication.intro.html)